# Is there a cleaner syntax for passing a member function to a base class?

Tags: c++, callback

Is there a cleaner syntax for passing a member function to a base class?

In the MRE below, is there a cleaner syntax than the one I am using for the lines:

```cpp
parse_array("email_addresses", [this]() { this->parse_email_address(); });
parse_array("phone_numbers", [this]() { this->parse_phone_number(); });
```

I want to make them "look pretty."

I would like them to read something like this:

```cpp
parse_array("email_addresses", parse_email_address);
parse_array("phone_numbers", parse_phone_number);
```

Here is a running program that demonstrates the first alternative above.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <functional>
#include <string>

class JSON_Parser
{
protected:
    template< class F >
    void parse_array(std::string const& key, F parse_element)
    {
        parse_key(key);
        parse_element();
    }
    void parse_key(std::string const& key)
    {}
};
class ContactParser : public JSON_Parser
{
public:
    void parse()
    {
        parse_array("email_addresses", [this]() { this->parse_email_address(); });
        parse_array("phone_numbers", [this]() { this->parse_phone_number(); });
    }
private:
    void parse_email_address()
    {}
    void parse_phone_number()
    {}
};
int main()
{
    ContactParser cp;
    cp.parse();
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

If necessary, I can change the signature of member function `parse_array` in the base class.

Note that making `parse_element` a virtual function will not work, because the derived class (in this example) has *two different functions* that are invoked when `parse_element` is called. That's why I want to pass them in as callbacks.

Note, as well, that using `std::function` in the signature of `parse_array` won't change anything at the call site.

Finally, note that I am not asking *how to pass a member function*. There are many Stack Overflow answers that cover that topic. I am asking whether the syntax above can be made to "look pretty."

##### Not what I am looking for

Of course, you can get "pretty" if you are willing to give the lamdas names, but that adds to the work a person would have to do when writing a derived class. The whole idea of class `JSON_Parser` is to simplify the task of writing a derived class, not add to it.

In addition, at least to my eye, the code reads better with anonymous closures placed inline.

```cpp
void parse()
{
    // This is not the solution I am looking for.
    auto parse_email_address = [this]() { this->parse_email_address(); };
    auto parse_phone_number = [this]() { this->parse_phone_number(); };

    // This looks "pretty."
    parse_array("email_addresses", parse_email_address);
    parse_array("phone_numbers", parse_phone_number);
}
```

##### A little context

As you may have surmised, class `JSON_Parser` is a lightweight tool that other parsers can build upon. It works with two other low-level classes: `JSON_Token` and `JSON_Lexer`.

The full code for member function `parse_array` is this:

```cpp
class JSON_Parser
{
    // Other necessities, and then...

    template< class F >
    void parse_array(std::string const& key, F parse_element)
    {
        parse_key(key);
        parse_symbol(':');
        parse_symbol('[');
        if (next_token_is('{') || next_token_is('"'))
            parse_element();
        while (next_token_is(','))
        {
            scan_token();
            parse_element();
        }
        parse_symbol(']');
    }
}
```

So, `parse_array` gives derived classes an easy way to parse a JSON array. It would be even easier, however, if the calling syntax were cleaner...

Comment: Do you understand the fundamental reason why callbacks must be passed this way, as anonymous closures with a captured `this`, here? Your proposed syntax will only work if the passed in function is a `static` class member. It is logically impossible, otherwise, for `parse()` to know which instance of an object the passed in class method must get called for.

Comment: Yeah, I get all that. I kind of figured the answer to my question is, "No!" But I thought I would ask anyway. I _really_ wanted it "look pretty!"

Comment: `[this]() { this->parse_email_address(); }` looks like a beautiful work of art, to me. The only thing I can think of would involve some tomfoolery with a deduced `this`, in C++23.

Comment: You can use pointer to member functions, but it changes the interface and I don't think it's cleaner than using lambdas. It's also less powerful. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/noa475Yov

Comment: You're right. That's more noise and less pretty! Toss is less powerful, and the buzzer goes, "Beeeeep!" Thanks, though, for posting the code at godbolt. I gave it a good read.

Comment: I assume `parse_array("email_addresses", [this]() { parse_email_address(); });` would not be considered a significant enough improvement?

Comment: @JaMiT – Actually, it is an improvement! As I explain in the edits to the OP, my purpose is to lighten the workload when a derived class is coded. I'm looking for clean and "natural" notations that don't require a lot of thinking on the part of the programmer (i.e., me!). Trivial as it may be, I like your idea.

Comment: Another possibility would perhaps be with a bind? `parse_array("email_addresses", std::bind(&ContactParser::parse_email_address, this));` Although it only qualifies as natural after you get familiar with the functionality...

Comment: I don't mind the complexity of `std::bind` so much as the location where it must be placed. If it were in the base class, that would be fine. As it must be placed at the call site, however, it is probably more complicated than what I want. The lambdas seem simpler.

Comment: Don't pass functions, pass objects. Which entails: don't *have* member functions like "parse_phone", have (possibly nested) classes like "phone_parser".

Comment: @Atmo No, don't use std::bind. It should have been deprecated

Comment: The fact you like or do not like the syntax of something is usually a sign you just are not used to that syntax (yet). Give it some time, the use of lambdas is idiomatic in C++  Just look at how people use std::sort or other STL algorithms.

Comment: I'm plenty experienced with lambdas.  On the other hand, _Don't pass functions, pass objects._ is something I have not heard stated so flatly. I'm going to chew on that. Of course, passing a closure object is just that: passing an _object,_ but that does not seem to be the sort of thing you are talking about.

Comment: I mean, if you have `class ContactParser` inheriting from `class JSON_Parser`, then why not `class EmailAddressParser` or `class `PhoneNumberParser`? They are not conceptually different. Or `ArrayParser` for that matter. An alternative is to have all of the above as standalone functions. In both case these are easy to compose. Member functions OTOH are not so nice. You can compose them but this involves unwieldy and non-uniform syntax.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: `std::bind` "*should have been deprecated*" for what reason and according to what source?